# Email to contact group suddenly bouncing as "too many addresses"

Tags: gmail

I have been sending for many years a daily message to a group of 199 names.  Yesterday, the group was rejected for "too many addresses".  I broke the group into 4 groups with 50 names.  The message is still bounced back.  How do I fix?

Comment: This may be related to the anti-spam measures announced by Google the other day along with their new postmaster tools.

Comment: A solution might be to create a google group.

Answer (score 2):

From [Message bounced due to sending limit - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839?hl=en)

> > Are you a Google Apps customer? Find out more about Google for Work
> >     [sending limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852) or [SMTP relay service sending
> >     limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491#sendinglimitsforrelay).
>
> In an effort to fight spam and prevent abuse, Google will temporarily
>   disable your account if you send messages to more than 500 recipients
>   or if you send a large number of undeliverable messages. If you use a
>   POP or IMAP client (for example: Microsoft Outlook or Apple Mail), you
>   may only send a message to 100 people at a time. Your account should
>   be re-enabled within 24 hours.
>
> If you communicate with the same group of people on a regular basis,
>   you might be interested in [Google Groups](http://groups.google.com/).
>
> If you send a large number of undeliverable messages, we suggest
>   verifying your contacts' email addresses. It's also important that
>   everyone you are sending mail to is willing to receive it.
>
> [Learn more](http://www.google.com/mail/help/bulk_mail.html) about
>   best practices for sending a large amount of mail through Gmail.